# The method If(boolean) is undefined for the type

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

Eclipse keeps giving me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
input cannot be resolved
The method If(boolean) is undefined for the type bai1DinhLuatCuLong
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
F cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I do not understand this. What do I need to fix? Why can't I use the `If()` function?

I've tried looking through Google and Bing, and I've double checked my Java examples book, but I could not work this out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class bai1DinhLuatCuLong
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    System.out.print("Giá trì cần tìm (F // q // r) : ");   
    char cantim = input.nextChar();

            // HERE THIS IS WHERE I PUT THE IF STATEMENT !!!
    If (cantim == 'F') {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Độ lớn của điện tích thứ nhất : ");
        double q1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Độ lớn của điện tích thứ hai : ");
        double q2 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Khoảng cách giữa 2 điện tích : ");
        double r = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Hệ số k sẽ tự động được đặt là 9*10^9 như trong hệ SI");
        double F = 9 * Math.pow(10,9) * Math.abs(q1) * Math.abs(q2) / Math.pow(r,2);
    }

    System.out.print("Độ lớn lực tương tác giữa 2 điện tích điểm : " + "\n Lưu ý E là *10");

    }
}
```

Comment: case matters. you can't use 'If', it **must** be 'if'

Comment: In your IDE and in the highlighted code you can see that `If` is not the same colour as the other keywords, compare with `public` and `static` Its the same colour as `Scanner` and `System`.

Comment: You probably don't want to delete this question - it could help someone in the future. Accept the correct answer below by clicking on the tick beneath the answer's score.

Comment: `Unresolved compilation problems` is always related to issues with the code itself and not with its behaviour or the interaction between classes and libraries. You can always detect those issues in your IDE. For example, in Eclipse you can check a resume with the Problems view.

Comment: I wonder how much research you did before postin this..

Comment: From the question, it's clear the OP tried to find the answer to his/her question him/herself, and the question has a single correct answer about programming and may be helpful to other programmes in the future. I think it should be upvoted significantly, even if it seems silly to experienced programmers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`If` does not have a large cap `I` in java: it should be `if`.

Answer (score 6):

`if (cantim == 'F')` it should be small **`i`**

or

You need to write a method

```
public boolean If(boolean test)
{
//Your logic.
}
```

But, based on your code, it seems you are looking for `"if"` statement than having new method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You want to do something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String cantim = input.next();

if (cantim.equals("F")) {
    System.out.println("If F");
} else {
    System.out.println("Out of F");
}
```